# ConvertJsonToSQL for Hive Insert query

Tags: hive, insert, hiveql, apache-nifi, hive-query

I want to insert Json to hive database.

I try to transform Json to SQL using ConvertJsonToSQL Ni-Fi processor. How can I use `PARTITION (....)` part into my query??

Can I do this or I should use ReplaceText processor for making query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Hive are you using? There are Hive 1.2 and Hive 3 versions of PutHiveStreaming and PutHive3Streaming (respectively) that let you put the data directly into Hive without having to issue HiveQL statements. For external Hive tables in ORC format, there are also ConvertAvroToORC (for Hive 1.2) and PutORC (for Hive 3) processors.

Assuming those don't work for your use case, you may also consider ConvertRecord with a FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter that generates the HiveQL with the PARTITION statement and such. It gives a lot more flexibility than trying to patch a SQL statement to turn it into HiveQL for a partitioned table.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that the Hive 3 NAR/components are not included with the NiFi release due to space reasons. You can find the Hive 3 NAR for NiFi 1.11.4 [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/nifi/nifi-hive3-nar/1.11.4/nifi-hive3-nar-1.11.4.nar).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @mattyb but I haven't PutHive3Streaming processor into my nifi (1.11.4)

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to the NAR (not included by default)